# can't load DistUpgradeViewGt3

Tags: package-management, upgrade

When upgrading 18.04 to 20.04 the terminal stops by telling me:
*

> can't load DistUpgradeViewGt3 (No module named
> 'DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeViewGt3')

- 

What can I do to get reddy with the upgrade?

Comment: It may help us understand what system you're using, and what command you're using that gives this error. ie. are you talking about a server? desktop? which desktop etc...   FYI:  It's **GTK3** not Gt3

Answer (score 0):

Before running upgrade you have to reinstall the [related package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=DistUpgradeViewGt) by

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3-distupgrade
```

Note: if you have errors while running `sudo apt-get update` command  - then please add them to your question by editing it.